# 3-way hold-out for picking between different ML models

Tags: training, data-preprocessing, cross-validation, testing

I have a dataset which is a time series. Before jumping on more heavy models such as LSTM, I wanted to test out the performance of linear models.

I have currently a 80/20 split between training and test. After I have trained my ridge regression using BayesSearchCV and 5-fold CV, I have arrived at a model. To visualize the performance of the model, I predict using the test set and make a parity plot.

The problem is that this will result in me using the test set to check whether the model performs well or that further tuning is required. This means that I have already used up the test set and that if I were to compare my current ridge model with a future LSTM model using the same test set would result in model selection bias. Would the correct approach to splitt the data in 3-parts, one for training, one for validation (even though I use CV to find hyperparameters) and the final test set to check the performance of the best model.

I struggle to find literature on this topic since most methods involving 3-way hold-out does not utlize CV and after using CV, this reduces to the classical training/test. I have found an article by Sebastian Raschka (see image), but the methods mentioned are only valid for classification and not regression. Since my data is a time series, they are thus dependent.

[image: Figure from Raschka (2018)] https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1811.12808